# How to abstract a change activity logic where I just need to change activity without adding anything in the intent?

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I have a simple activity, when it creates, it will do some check, and maybe switch to another activity if user is not login.

**If I do something like this, it works:**

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        if (userPreference?.memberRegistered == false) {
            val intent = Intent(this, AuthActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

**But if I abstract it to another method, it won't work.**

```
class HomeActivity : SalectActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        if (userPreference?.memberRegistered == false) {
            goToActivity(AuthActivity::class.java)
        }
    }

    fun <T: Any> goToActivity(activity: Class<T>) {
        val intent = Intent(this, activity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

**The errors are:**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{nz.salect.handset/nz.salect.handset.HomeActivity}:
>   
> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {nz.salect.handset/java.lang.Class}; have you declared
>   this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>   
> .......
>   Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {nz.salect.handset/java.lang.Class}; have you declared this activity
>   in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>   
> .......

The error occurs at that `startActivity()` call.

**This is the Manifest, of course the AuthActivity is there, otherwise the normal way won't work as well.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nz.salect.handset">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AuthActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What happened here?

How to fix this and what did i miss?

Comment: can you update your question with Manifest?

Comment: try this `val intent = Intent(this, activity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class >

You are getting above exception because you not any activity  **`activity::class.java`** in manifest file that's why you are getting `ActivityNotFoundException`

when you use `val intent = Intent(this, activity::class.java)` means you `intent` to another activity named "activity" not for your  `AuthActivity`

As per [my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663877/how-to-abstract-a-change-activity-logic-where-i-just-need-to-change-activity-wit/49663998#comment86337630_49663877)

Use this

```
fun <T: Any> goToActivity(activity: Class<T>) {
        val intent = Intent(this, activity)
        startActivity(intent)
}
```

Instead of this

```
fun <T: Any> goToActivity(activity: Class<T>) {
        val intent = Intent(this, activity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: It works! But why it works when I call it without extracting to a function. `val intent = Intent(this, AuthActivity::class.java)` . Isn't it the same?

Comment: @AlbertGao no in your `goToActivity` function  it will start activity for  `activity::class.java` instead of `AuthActivity::class.java` in your manifeat file your didn't have any activity `activity::class.java` that's why you are getting `ActivityNotFoundException`

Comment: because the line `val intent = Intent(this, activity::class.java)` means you intent to another activity named "activity" meanwhile  `val intent = Intent(this, activity)` this line call AuthActivity because you pass `AuthActivity::class.java` param

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat  Thanks both of you. My bad. Because I already pass the class definition there as the parameter.